# How to set the in-param pointer key value correctly into the pointer in my struct?

Tags: c

Alright, so I have the following in-param: `uint8_t * key`

In the function such as `void functionname(uint8_t * key)`
i want to store **ONLY** the key itself and not the pointer to key within a new pointer called `uint8_t * pointerKey` (which belongs to a struct). How do I do to store only the actual key value of `key` and not the pointer of key into pointerKey?

is it `pointerKey = &key`
or `pointerKey = *key`
or `pointerKey = key`?
haven't really gotten the grasp of this part of pointers yet, so clearing this upp would help me in the future.

Comment: Please show the code as a code block instead of code snippets embedded in your text. What exactly do you mean with "*i want to store ONLY the key itself and not the pointer to key*"? The parameter `uint8_t * key` is a pointer to `uint8_t` and the new pointer is the same type, so it can store the same kind of data.

Comment: `uint8_t *key` and `uint8_t *pointerKey` are the same type; is this intentional? What does _in-param_ mean in this context?

Comment: `&key` is the address of the variable `key`.  `key` is a variable whose value is the address of a `uint8_t`.  The expression `*key` evaluates to the value of the `uint8_t` at the address store in `key`.  So `&key` is of type `uint8_t **`, `key` is of type `uint8_t *`, and `*key` is of type `uint8_t`.  If you have a `uint8_t *` named `pointerKey`, then you probably want to write `*pointerKey = *key`, but you must first ensure that `pointerKey` contains a valid address.

Comment: How many bytes of memory does `key` point to?  Just one, or an arbitrary number?  (I'm guessing an arbitrary number, otherwise there'd be no point in passing `key` as a pointer.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends if the argument for `functionname(uint8_t *key)` is address of an integer, or pointer for integer array. If it's an integer:

```
void foo_integer(uint8_t* ptr)
{
    printf("foo, ptr = %d\n", *ptr); //read the value
    *ptr = 123; //changes the variable which ptr points to
}
```

You can use this function by pass the address of integer variable:

```
int key = 0;
foo_integer(&key);
printf("key changed: %d\n", key); //key is changed to 123
```

---

If the argument is an array, you just pass the pointer, for example

```
void foo_integer_array(uint8_t* ptr, int count)
{
    if (count < 0) return;
    ptr[0] = 1000; //okay
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) 
        printf("arr %d, ", ptr[i]);
    printf("\n");

    //*ptr = ? <- don't dereference ptr, we are not allowed to change it
}

int arr[3] = { 1,2,3 };
foo_integer_array(arr, sizeof(arr)/sizeof(*arr));
```

You just pass `arr` to `foo_integer_array` (the array `arr` will decay to pointer, it is already an address), you wouldn't pass the address of the `arr`.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I'd suppose that your `uint8_t * key` input parameter contains actual data of `uint8_t` type, but not the pointer to other location in memory.
So then, let's consider the next case:

1. Suppose you have a struct, called *KeyHolder*:

```
struct KeyHolder {
  uint8_t *pointerKey;
}
```

2. You've pointed that you want to store actual `key` value within a **new pointer**:

```
void functionname(uint8_t * key) {
  // get the actual value of key
  uint8_t key_value = *key;
  // allocate memory for struct
  struct KeyHolder *kh = (KeyHolder *) malloc(sizeof(KeyHolder));
  // allocate memory for storing key value
  kh->pointerKey = (uint8_t*) malloc(sizeof(uint8_t));
  *(kh->pointerKey) = key_value;

   // Do actual work ...
   // Don't forget to free allocated memory
   free(kh.pointerKey);
   free(kh);
}
```

Therefore, after getting the pointer of type 'uint8_t' you can store any value of specified type, in your case - *key* value.
If you don't want to allocate memory for 'KeyHolder' struct you should write it like that:

```
struct KeyHolder kh;
kh.pointerKey = (uint8_t *) malloc(sizeof(uint8_t));
*(kh.pointerKey) = key;
```